# Where are the Diablominer Config Settings stored in Mac OSX?

Tags: mac, miner-configuration, diablominer

I can't find them any where.  Note, I'll admit I'm a new Mac user, so I may be missing an obvious location, however, I can't find it in my personal folder.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct locations might be either `~/Library/Application Support/Diablominer` or `~/.diablominer`

Of course it might be in in an incorrect location. Super Meat Boy, for instance, stores its configuration inside the .app itself (brrr). To check there you have to right click the app and "show package contents".

The best way to find this configuration file, if you already know at least the file name, is casting `find ~ -name filename`, hoping at least it is somewhere in your home directory.

Comment: It's inside the app bundle for the implementation that I'm using.  I didn't realize that was even possible. :/

Comment: @RLH , could you tell, where exactly 'inside bundle' can it be, please.

Comment: @OleksandrBolotov he means it's inside the .app - you open it with right click -> "show package contents"